# Selenium Python space act as new line

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

When I am trying to invoke :

```
element.send_keys("Hello World")
```

It prints the second word in the new line and even when if I am using Unicode as:

```
element.send_keys(u"Hello\ue00dWorld")
```

Anyhow it prints in a new line.
What can I do to make it work as expected?
I am using python selenium webdriver version is 3.11.0.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by expected ?

Comment: Your binary versions please

Comment: I expect space to be space but not a new line

Comment: Are you sure there is no blackmagic JS that parse spaces into newlines? Like inputs to add tags (when you hit space, it submit the tag)

Comment: No, because the same script is working fine from other pc. The difference is in operation systems one is Fedora and other where is not working is ubuntu server.

Comment: @DebanjanB how can I provide you a binary version?

Comment: @serj _Selenium Client_ / _WebDriver_ / _WebClient_ variant and versions please.

Comment: @DebanjanB I am using python selenium webdriver version is 3.11.0

Comment: @DebanjanB any ideas?

Comment: @serj You are yet to update the question with the required information in terms of _Selenium Client / WebDriver / WebClient variant and versions_

Comment: @DebanjanB I have updated my question that is what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use VNC at your server. At least I got the same situation with Ubuntu 18.04, Selenium 3.141.59, ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 and TigerVNC 1.3.10.

Unfortunately, it's a **bug of Chromedriver**.

https://monorail-prod.appspot.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1300

But it was archived without a fix in 2017.

I'd recommend do not to use VNC and try Xvfb instead.